# Visual Studio wants to compile my C file using C++ and fails

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have VS 2022 project, which looks like that:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" {
   #include "test.h"
}

int main()
{
     
   std::cout << "Hello World!:  " << MYTEST.a;
}
```

Then I use the following C - Header:

test.h

```
typedef struct {
    int a;
} TEST;

const TEST MYTEST = {
    .a = 8 //fails here
};
```

Unfortunately this fails with the error: "Use of designated initializers requires at least /std:c++20"

I wonder if VS tries to compile my test.h file using a cpp - compiler...

Comment: Header files are not "compiled". Including a header file is like copy-pasting its entire contents into the source file where the `#include` is.

Comment: Besides, you're already using non-C constructs in the "C" header file. That `extern "C"` part is invalid in C. You can't include that header file in a C source file.

Comment: Visual Studio doesn't *have* a C compiler, only a "C mode" for its C++ compiler.  And it doesn't have support for many features that only ever existed in C.  But you will be running it in C++ mode anyway, because the source file has a ".cpp" extension.

Comment: So the simple solution is to read the error message, and do what it asks you to do: Add the `/std:c++20` option to your compiler settings.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It should compile my MYTEST definition it in main.cpp using some sort of c mode. Why would changing it to cpp20 fix that? Thanks for your answer :)

Comment: @Niclas That's not how it's supposed to work. I think you misunderstand what [`extern "C"`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/language_linkage) is about.

Comment: I understand that the extern C is about linkage. But let us suppose there is no Cpp20 yet, how would I have fixed my problem back then? Surely the compiler must know that it has to compile a "extern C" file differently...

Comment: Again, no that's not how it works. `extern "C"` doesn't tell the C++ to compile in a different "mode" using a completely different language. If you want to use C++20 features then either you must require a C++20 capable compiler, or stop using the feature and use other way to initialize your structures.

Comment: @Niclas No, like the earlier comment said, `extern "C"` has no effect on which compiler or compiler options are picked. Like you said, it's about linkage, nothing more.

Comment: The expectation of C here is odd. Both files use syntax exclusive to C++. If you tried to compile it as C, it would fail.

Comment: This was my minimum example to demonstrate the problem. In my real example, I have a C - Unit and there is a C Header which exports a const variable called MYTEST. Surely I could have made this variable visible back in 2019 to CPP Code...

Comment: Why not simply use `/std:c++20` (or `/std:c++latest`) and be done?

Comment: `extern "C"` is not valid C syntax. What were you expecting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your compilation unit is a `.cpp` file that very clearly contains C++ code, not C code. Header files are not compiled separately but simply copy-pasted into the translation unit by the preprocessor.

Also, the code in your header file is C++ as well. It wouldn't be valid in C. `extern "C"` does not make C++ code to be C code. It only declares language linkage of the entities contained in the block following it. The contents of the block are still C++ code. And `extern "C"` itself is not valid C syntax.

So, you are writing C++, not C at all, and you need a C++ compiler. However the syntax `.a = 8` in aggregate initialization is only supported since C++20 in C++. So you need to set your compiler to compile in C++20 mode or later.

---

Also note that in C++, in contrast to C, non-template non-volatile `const` variables at namespace scope have *internal* linkage by default. So regardless of you putting it in a `extern "C"` block, it won't be visible in other translation units, e.g. a C translation unit anyway. So `extern "C"` there is pointless.

---

If your goal is to define the variable in C code, then your header should contain only the declaration

```
extern const TEST MYTEST;
```

in the `extern "C"` block and then you should have a `.c` file containing the definition

```
const TEST MYTEST = {
   .a = 8 //fails here
};
```

which you then need to compile separately as C and then link the output for the two translation units together.

Both files of course need the definition of `TEST` as well, so the standard approach is to include the same header file in both the `.cpp` translation unit and the `.c` translation unit, but to add `extern "C"` conditionally via the preprocessor:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif
    typedef struct {
        int a;
    } TEST;

    extern const TEST MYTEST;
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: you edit is what I am looking for. Thank you!
It immediately solved my problem!